# Extract number after dash "-" if there is one

Tags: excel, excel-formula, split, find, extract

Excel Problem.
Let's say I have 2 cells.
A1: HE11294419-12
A2 11296581

I would like to extract the number after the dash found in A1, in another cell.
In case of A2 - the cell should say just "1".

So the result should be
B1: 12
B2: 1

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- Always just one dash in string
- In case no dash, extract the last number of string

Try in `B1`:

```
=IFERROR(MID(A1,SEARCH("-",A1)+1,LEN(A1)),RIGHT(A1,1))
```

Drag down.

In case the second assumption is wrong, and it always needs to be one just change `..RIGHT(A1,1)` to `..1`

Answer (score 0):

You can try below formula. It will return first numbers after `-` if there are multiple `-` in cell.

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("-",A1)),1,TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",REPT(" ",100)),100,100)))
```